# Moving Average: question on Wiki derivation

Tags: probability, average

I'm reading [Wiki's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) entry on a moving average and have questions on the derivation of $\textit{SMA}_{k, next}$.  Specifically, does anyone know step (2) was derived from step (1)?  The terms in the right cancel, but I still am confused how (2) is derived.  Thanks

$$
 \begin{align}
        \textit{SMA}_{k} &= \frac{p_{n-k+1} + p_{n-k+2} \cdots + p_{n}}{k} \\
        &= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=n-k+1}^{n} p_{i}
    \end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
   \textit{SMA}_{k, next} &= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=n-k+2}^{n+1} p_{i}  \\
              &= \frac{1}{k} \Big( \underbrace{ p_{n-k+2} + p_{n-k+3} + \dots + p_{n} + p_{n+1} }_{ \sum_{i=n-k+2}^{n+1} p_{i} } + \underbrace{ p_{n-k+1} - p_{n-k+1} }_{= 0} \Big) && (1)\\
              &= \underbrace{ \frac{1}{k} \Big( p_{n-k+1} + p_{n-k+2} + \dots + p_{n} \Big) }_{= \textit{SMA}_{k, prev}} - \frac{p_{n-k+1}}{k} + \frac{p_{n+1}}{k}  && (2)\\
              &= \textit{SMA}_{k, prev} + \frac{1}{k} \Big( p_{n+1} - p_{n-k+1} \Big) && (3)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: In (2) there is p_{n-k+1} inside the bracket which is not in (1) therefore is has to be subracted. p_{n+1} is just taken out of the bracket..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of this demonstration is to write $SMA_{k,n+1}$ in terms of $SMA_{k,n}$ (probably for computation reasons, its easier to add a few numbers than a lot).

They started writing $SMA_{k,n+1}$ and if you compare this with $SMA_{k,n}$, you will notice that the term $p_{n-k+1}$ (the first term in $SMA_{k,n}$) is missing, and the last term $p_{n+1}$ that is not in $SMA_{k,n}$, so they added and substracted the term $p_{n-k+1}$ and then separated the term $p_{n+1}$ from the summation.
Probably the confusion comes from the fact that the the term $p_{n-k+1}$ was located in the first position in the summation in (2).